# I'm trying to pass a value to a controller from a url in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble passing a string variable to a controller in ASP.NET MVC 5. As far as I know my code should work but the controller just receives a null value no matter what I do.

First off I have my `route.config` above the default route, here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Serial number",
       url: "serial/{letterCase}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase="upper" }
);
```

and here is my simple code in the home controller

```
public ActionResult Serial(string letterCase)
{
        var serial = "ASPNETMVC5ATM1";

        if(letterCase == "lower")
        {
            return Content(serial.ToLower());
        }

        return Content(serial);
}
```

So in theory if I browse to the url `home/serial/lower`, it should accept the lower string but it isn't working I even tried using "home/serial?lower" and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Your route definition says the url to match is `serial/{lettercase}`. It does not say anything about the controller name ! So it will match for `yoursite.com/serial/lower` or `yoursite.com/serial/anystring` **But not** `yoursite.com/home/serial/lower`

So with your current route definition, You can access your action method without home(controller name) in the url. That is `yoursite.com/serial/somestring`

If you want  to make it work with `home/serial/lower` url pattern, you need to add the controller part to the url in your route definition.

The below will direct any request to `home/serial/{anystring}` to your Serial method in Home controller.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Serial number",
            url: "home/serial/{letterCase}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", 
                                                                      letterCase="upper" }
           );
```

Also this specific route definitions should always above the default route definitions. The order really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have placed this specific route **before** any other route definitions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Serial number",
    url: "serial/{letterCase}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase="upper" }
);
```

Now if you call `serial/lower` (and **not** `home/serial/lower`) you should get the expected results.